# extraer valor del JSON en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, datatables, jsonobject

deseo migrar el valor que tiene la propiedad **base**
**[{"tax":"9996","value":"0.00","base":"300.00"}]** a la columna total_free

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTA: base es una variable que tiene un valor diferente en cada registro

lo primero que intento es extraer el valor del json,  asi que intente hacer esto:

***SELECT other_taxes , JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes, '$.base')  as base  from documents  order by id desc***

sin embargo la columna **base** sigue en null

despues mi idea es actualizar la columna total_free

**UPDATE documents SET total_free= if (other_taxes is null, null, ???)**

como deberia hacer ayuda por favor

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Si lo que quieres es obtener el valor que hay en la propiedad `base` del JSON, la consulta es esta: `SELECT other_taxes, JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes,  '$[*].base') FROM ...`

Comment: Si en `other_taxes` hay sólo un objeto en el array, podrías hacer algo así: `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes,  '$[0].base') AS base FROM ...` Ese es uno de los aspectos que no es claro en la pregunta, ¿`other_taxes` podría contener en cada fila varios objetos JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la columna `other_taxes` tienes un JSON Array (eso es lo que significa `[ ... ]` en JSON).

Por tanto, no puedes buscar el valor de `base` como si fuera un objeto simple: `'$.base'`.

Si lo que quieres es obtener el valor de `base` del primer objeto que haya en `other_taxes` la consulta sería esta:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes,  '$[0].base') AS base 
FROM ...
```

Y si quieres obtener el valor de todas las propiedades `base`:

```
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes, '$[*].base') AS bases
FROM ...
```

Consideremos que `other_taxes` tuviera datos como estos:

```
[
  {"tax":"9996","value":"0.00","base":"300.00"},  
  {"tax":"9996","value":"0.00","base":"400.00"}
]
```

La primera consulta te daría esto:

```
"300.00"
```

Y la segunda consulta te daría esto:

```
["300.00", "400.00"]
```

Para más detalles consulta el apartado [*Searching and Modifying JSON Values*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths) en el Manual de Referencia.

---

### Actualizar

Asumiendo que `other_taxes` es una columna de tipo `JSON` y tú quisieras pasar los valores de la propiedad `base` a dicha columna, podrías lograrlo del siguiente modo:

```
UPDATE documents 
SET
    total_free = JSON_EXTRACT(other_taxes, '$[*].base')
WHERE -- aquí tu criterio
```

**ADVERTENCIA:** Considera hacer una copia de seguridad de tus tablas antes de ejecutar consultas en fase de prueba que podrían modificarla masivamente.